# How can display tally values from array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to display values from array as table format

```
@array = {"Very Good"=>24, "Good"=>81, "Regular"=>3, "Bad"=>1, "Very Bad"=>1}
```

I have this array displaed but i want to display information as table format

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <% @array.each do |info|%>
  <tr>
    <td><% info[0].try("name") %></td>
    <td><% info[0].try("count") %></td>
  </tr>      
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I tried this code but it's displaying the information as row and i want to display values separated.

```
<% @array.map do |info| %>
 <%=  info %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the view display but i'm trying to display as table format (organized) with column name and column count.

```
<%= @array.tally %>
```

It displays with brackets:

```
{"Very Good"=>24, "Good"=>81, "Regular"=>3, "Bad"=>1, "Very Bad"=>1}
```

Comment: It seems you're mixing up stuff here; it looks like you want to go over the pairs of keys -> values, but don't have a clear idea of how they're structured. Have you taken a look at [Hash#to_a](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-to_a)?

Comment: `@array = { ... }` – despite the variable name, that's a _hash_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#When iterating over hashes, two placeholder variables are needed to represent each key/value pair.

```
@array = {"Very Good"=>24, "Good"=>81, "Regular"=>3, "Bad"=>1, "Very Bad"=>1}

@array.each do |key, value|
   p key // "Very Good, Good, Regular, Bad, Very Bad
   p value // 24,81, 3, 1, 1
end
```

[image]

Sort by with `hash` with value `sort_by{|k, v| v}`. If you sort with key, you can change `sort_by{|k, v| k}`

```
sortASC = Hash[@array.sort_by{|k, v| v}]
sortDESC =  Hash[@array.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]
```

[image]

Comment: just a last question how can i order by key asc?

Comment: Well i was trying to get a solution without hash just using each do

Answer (score 3):

```rb
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Count</td>
  </tr>
  <% @array.each do |key, value|%>
  <tr>
    <td><%= key %></td>
    <td><%= value %></td>
  </tr>      
  <% end %>
</table>
```

you also forgot the `=` to display the data  `<%=` not `<%`.

Comment: just a last question how can i order by key asc?